# what is the best practice to search in mvc eTrade website on Host

Tags: search, model-view-controller, search-engine, google-search, solar

I have a MVC ETrade website and I want to know what is the best way to build or implement   search engine for my website BackAdmin and FrontEnd
-can i implement solar.net on hosting like SmartAspNest or GoDaddy 
- is it better to use google custom search in my website
-is there any resource to get good and strong classes to help me to build my search
please help me with your experience in this topic 
thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

best practice to search in mvc eTrade website on Host if you have your own server you can use solar but if you`ll use host like godaddy you have to make your own model for multisearch